# Count occurence of values between 2 dynamic dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, count

I have a table with a row for each events for a user. I want to retrieve every user who got 2 or more events in **the same week** *(with up to 7 days between them)*.

Event Table :

```
id   -   user_id   -   date
 1   -       1     -   2015/04/02
 2   -       1     -   2015/04/05
 3   -       1     -   2015/09/12
 4   -      14     -   2016/01/21
 5   -      14     -   2016/02/18
```

So the expected results should be

```
user_id   -   count(date in same week)
 1        -         2
```

The user_id 14 should not be in results, because its events are not in the same week.

Does someone know how to do it entirely in MySQL ?

Comment: Calender week or up to 7 days between them ?

Comment: Up to 7 days between them. I will update question, thanks.

Comment: And up to 7 days from the first occurence? E.G.  1-april, 3-april,5-april,8april . what should be the result?

Comment: I just need the list of users with at least two in same 7 days. The count isn't important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need the list of the user_id's that have more then 1 occurrences in 7 days, then you can use `EXISTS()` with `DATEDIFF()`

```
SELECT distinct user_id
FROM EventTable e
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM EventTable e2
             WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF(e.date,e2.date)) < 7
              AND e.user_id = e2.user_id)
```

Comment: `>` should be `<`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to know if they have 2 in the same week, you can use a self-join where the condition is that the second table has an event within 7 days of the first.

```
SELECT distinct a.user_id
FROM events AS a
JOIN events AS b 
ON a.user_id = b.user_id 
    AND b.date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(a.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(a.date, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```